# Dual booting with diffferent primary graphics cards

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, multi-boot, pci-express

I need to be able to dual boot run two OSes, each having using a different PCI-E graphics card.

OS A - card A (primary, 16 lanes PCI-e x16 slot)
OS B - card B (secondary, 8 lanes PCI-e x16 slot)

"A " works most of the times but "B"... thing is if I plug DVI cable from card A to card B and reboot computer it won't make it to even POST screen. I am just getting no signal on the monitor.

Now, I can temporarily have OS B work with card A, fiddle inside it installing / uninstalling / enabling / disabling hardware drivers / components then reboot and occasionally OS B - card B will be picked up by pre-boot loader screens, bootloader and then properly work inside OS B.

What I am looking for is a  way to make the POST / bootloader screens show up when DVI cable is attached to either card. Mainboard is an extremely cheap and old [Asus M2N-SLI deluxe](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/M2NSLI_Deluxe/) (notice I am not interested in its SLI function), however reading through its user manual it comes clear that what I am looking for should be supported with this MB. And, well, it is supported, just not always.

Comment: how exactly are you running two operating systems sequentially?

Comment: The computer is probably making it to the POST screen, you just can't see it because you have no monitor connected to the primary video card.

Comment: @Ramhound by rebooting while in one of them and choosing to boot into the other one from bootloader menu

Comment: @DavidSchwartz yes, you are right, sorry for not mentioning

Comment: @kellogs - So you are dual-booting.  I am not sure `sequentially booting` accurately describes what your trying to do.  That indicates you are booting to one operating system and from that operating system you boot into another.  `sequentially` is a *serial sequence*.

Comment: This is quite possible and it should just work, **but** : Your motherboiard firmware (aka BIOS) will POST on its primary graphics card. In order to see it boot you will need to enter the firmware each time you want to boot a different OS and set the matching primary card. Often these are labels 'internal graphics, 'PCI', 'PEG-1', PEG-2', "PEG-3', ... (PEG is PCI-express graphics).   Depending on your motherboard you may have fewer choices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. The motherboard will choose one of the cards as the primary and the POST information will appear there always.

What might be possible, assuming you have 2 monitors, is if your secondary monitor has two inputs, you could either take a second output from the primary card (if it has 2 connectors) or use a splitter cable to feed the primary card's output to the secondary input of monitor 2.

If you only have 1 monitor, you will simply need to use the monitor controls to switch inputs.

Comment: ok, first paragraph makes sense. The rest of your answer is out of scope I guess. Brb after some more fiddling.

Answer (score 0):

While Julian's post answers my question, I am posting here the way I manage to use those OSes with two cards. I found that OS B will pick up card B this way:

- have primary card A connected to screen;
- run to bootloader, select OS B with keyboard
- switch monitor to card B
- hit enter

Screen will go off as OS B boots, but it will turn on again after some time. And that was that.